# How can I use my android device to control PC by using USB

Tags: android, usb

I am wonder to use my android device to control Pc by USB like a Joystick，but i have no idea about it.Is there any suggestions to do this ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make a Socket connection between you android device and you PC.
ADB is a find choice, send your command to your pc Clinet.Parse it, and deal with it.